# lightweight publish/subscribe framework in java

Tags: java, frameworks, publish-subscribe

Is there a good lightweight framework for java that provides the publish/subscribe pattern?

Some ideal features

- Support for generics
- Registration of multiple subscribers to a publisher
- API primarily interfaces and some useful implementations
- purely in-memory, persistence and transaction guarantees not required.

I know about JMS but that is overkill for my need. The publish/subscribed data are the result of scans of a file system, with scan results being fed to another component for processing, which are then processed before being fed to another and so on.

EDIT:
All within the same process. PropertyChangeListener from beans doesn't quite cut it, since it's reporting changes on properties, rather than publishing specific items. I could shoehorn ProprtyChangeListener to work by having a "last published object" property, and so published objects. PropertyChangeListeners don't support generics, and are entrenched in property change semantics, rather than pure publish/subscribe. The java.util Observer/Observable pattern would be good, but Oberver is a concrete class.

Comment: Within one process? Or across many processes and machines?

Comment: Within a single process.

Comment: Is this a Spring application?

Comment: @skaffman, yes the application is implemented in spring. The part I'm focusing on here that needs a simple publish/subscribe pattern is a RIA client, which uses spring to configure the interfaces to web service endpoints. The objects being published/subscribed are all local.

Comment: I'm a little confused with the references to JMS.  If you are within a single process could one (or a couple) thread executor pools be adequate?  If the threads are dynamically subscribing then could a loose wrapper around a series of BlockingQueue(s) work?  A thread could choose to subscribe to a job by take-ing from the right queue.  I've seen performance problems with various JMS implementations when you have portions of the work queue that are faster than others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JMS is as light or heavy as you configure it. We use for example [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq) in one project with an in memory queue. It is easy to setup, doesn't need any JNDI based configuration and is really easy to use.

I believe that JMS as an API for Message Pub/Sub is as easy as it gets. (And not easier ;)

Comment: Actually... for the publish/subscribe aka observer pattern the simplest and most basic thing there is... is the javax.beans package. ;) (PropertyChangeListener, PropertyChangeEvent, PropertyChangeSupport ...)

Comment: @user268396, fair enough. For simple POJO state change pub/sub JavaBeans property listening is even simpler.

Comment: @user268396 - I'm afraid PropertyChangeListener won't fit here. See my edit for reasons.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. Perhaps was too hasty in dismissing JMS?

Comment: @mdma, maybe, I thought too before that JMS is all heavyweight J2EE, but it is actually quite lightweight if you pick the right provider. And if interface/provider separation is important for you, then JMS is probably the right approach.

Answer (score 32):

It seems this fits the requirements:

[EventBus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) from Google Guava Library - *"Publish-subscribe-style communication between components without requiring the components to explicitly register with one another"*. It can also be an [AsyncEventBus](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/AsyncEventBus.html) that will dispatch events on another thread.

Some extra options to consider:

1. If it's in same process it's possible the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern can be used. Subscribers can add listeners and receive event notifications. [Observable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) is already part of the Java API.
2. [FFMQ](http://ffmq.sourceforge.net/) is a full Java, *light-weight*, Fast JMS 1.1 Queue implementation.

Comment: The Observer pattern seems to imply a knowledge of the observable and observer whereas true publish/subscribe permits code independence. EventBus from Guava looks better for this.

Comment: Another option would be using [MBassador](https://github.com/bennidi/mbassador) -- it is similar to Guava EventBus but claims to have better processing performance (see [benchmarks](https://github.com/bennidi/eventbus-performance)). On the downside it looks like it hasn't been updated for a while now.

Answer (score 8):

Since you're using Spring, I don't know if you're aware that Spring has its own [lightweight event framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events). It's used primarily within the framework itself, but it's perfectly usable by application code.

By default, it's synchronous pub/sub, but you can make it asynchronous using an `ApplicationEventMulticaster`.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) is also a good candidate. Especially with the [publish-subscribe pattern](http://camel.apache.org/publish-subscribe-channel.html)

Camel can be embedded and is lightweight. It proposes Enterprise Integration Patterns - many useful tools for integration, inside an application or even with other actors (hence 'Integration').

It compares to [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) but more complete IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If you are crossing process boundaries then some degree of "weight" is going to be incurred. Why do you say that JMS is heavyweight? The API is quite simple? There are supposedly light-weight implementations, for example [link text](http://ffmq.sourceforge.net/) heavier costs such a persistence and transactionality are optional.

What do you need that is lighter than this?

Answer (score 0):

Bob Lee has a `QueueFile` class at http://snipt.org/GWm/ that you might find interesting. It's a simple persistent queue and could be used by multiple consumers. It sounds like you don't need persistence, but since the whole thing is so lightweight it could still be useful.

Comment: You could access latest implementation from here: https://github.com/square/tape/blob/master/tape/src/main/java/com/squareup/tape/QueueFile.java