# android publish/subscribe pattern

Tags: android, publish-subscribe

Is there a publish/subscribe pattern in android?

What I want to achieve is I have this class that can notify interested party of an event. Then the interested party can do whatever it needs.

Coming from a .net microsoft world, this sort of thing are build in.

Do android have something similar, or I have to write some thing like an observer pattern?

Comment: You can try out PServiceBus(http://pservicebus.codeplex.com/), You just need to install the .Net ESB Server and use the Java Client(https://github.com/rpgmaker/PServiceBus-Java-Client) to connect to it. With it, you can do communication between Java and any .NET app and even communication between Java and Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are speaking in terms of passing events/messages among classes within your application. So this question probably goes down to Java implementation of such a pattern.

There's nothing actually already baked in (i.e. no `event` system class), one of the most common way to let a class spread an event/message is the *Listener* technique (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), [Vogel](http://www.vogella.de/articles/DesignPatternObserver/article.html), [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07265/index.html)).

There are frameworks too, as from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032827/lightweight-publish-subscribe-framework-in-java).

If you are concerned about async messages across thread/processes in Android, then there are [Handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and (for inter-process) [Parcelables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html).

Comment: Thanks was hoping for something built in instead of cooking my own observer pattern.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: hmmm seem so tightly couple to context and intent. I have a normal class that has no knowledge of context, intent, etc. For pure example, a class responsible to counts till 100, when it finished counting till 100 it can notify other objects that are interested in this event.

Comment: In Android this is generally a good way to do this. Also note you can optimise by using LocalBroadcastReciver

Answer (score 7):

I found LocalBroadcastManager the most suitable for in app pub-sub style.
You can always use observers but this one makes life more easy:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html

EDIT: 
It seems like there are couple of solutions nowdays. They surely worth mentioning:

- [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) as mentioned previously
- [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)
- [RxBus](https://github.com/AndroidKnife/RxBus)

Comment: As mentioned below. For a more robust solution I would also reccomend the excellent EventBus library from greenrobot.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit old, but it was top google result for "android publish subscribe".

Android's [Local Broadcast Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) is also an option. It has some advantages over globally broadcasting intents.

It is still tightly coupled to intents though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I have been using EventBus by GreenRobot. It is great so far. Much more loosely coupled to intents than BroadcastReceivers and LocalBroadcastManagers. Check it out here: http://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/