# Publish/subscribe for Android apps

Tags: android, publish-subscribe

I want to create an Android application that shows ongoing events to users (missile launches in different regions, based on the user's location. This isn't a game, it's one of the perks of living close to Gaza).

I can use GCM for push notifications, but I have to do this on a device-by-device basis. I would like instead to offer a few subscription channels based on the client's location, and send data from the server to all clients listening to that channel.

Is there a Google API for this, or do I have to implement it myself (maybe by using XMPP), reducing battery life quite a bit?

Comment: I don't see how GCM isn't an option to perform that task. You simply tag the updates from the server and make the users subscribe to that tag (channel). If you're looking for other alternatives though, you can use backend-as-a-service startups like Parse and Kinvey.

Comment: To me, it sounds like you need someone to cook up an Amazon SNS->GCM gateway of some form.

Comment: @CommonWare, that sounds like a *great* idea. I'll see if in the time available we can create this gateway, it seems rather straightforward. If we add iOS's push-notification's service to the mix, we're going to have a real good platform useful for a lot of people.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android publish/subscribe pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362241/android-publish-subscribe-pattern)

Comment: The title is a bit misleading. For internal android pub/sub implementation see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362241/android-publish-subscribe-pattern/16281259#16281259 . What this post is talking about is a GCM /push notification replacment, maybe the title should be modified

Comment: This question is almost 5 years old, I'm sure a lot of things have changed since then.